# Prove Levi-Civita connection is torsion free

Tags: riemannian-geometry, connections

I am trying to understand the proof that the Levi-Civita connection is torsion free. In the [notes](http://www.matematik.lu.se/matematiklu/personal/sigma/Riemann.pdf%20''notes') in theorem 6.8 it is written that

$g(\nabla_XY, Z) - g(\nabla_YX, Z) = g(Z, [X,Y])$

proves that connection is torsion free. My question is how do we show that the above relation satisfies the 0 torsion definition

$\nabla_XY - \nabla_YX = [X, Y]$?

Comment: If the relation is true for any vector field $Z$ then this follows from the fact that $g$ is bilinear and positive definite.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Swap the two arguments in the $g$ on the right-hand side, and move it to the left. Now you have
$$
g(\nabla_XY, Z) - g(\nabla_YX, Z) - g( [X,Y], Z) = 0
$$
Use the bilinearity of $g$ to change that into
$$
g(\nabla_XY- \nabla_YX - [X,Y], Z) = 0.
$$

Since this holds for every $Z$, and $g$ is nondegenerate, you get that 
$$
\nabla_XY- \nabla_YX - [X,Y] = 0.
$$